# using bitarray to grab bits and build new value

Tags: c#, bitarray

If i take a uint value = 2921803 (0x2C954B), which is really a 4 byte package (4B 95 2C 00)
and i want to get the 16 least significant bits of the byte version of it using bitarray, how would i go about it?

This is how i am trying to do it:

```
byte[] bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(value);  //4B 95 2C 00  - bytes are moved around
BitArray bitArray = new BitArray(bytes); //entry [0] shows value for 1101 0010 (bits are reversed)
```

At this point, i am all turned around.  I did try this:

```
byte[] bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(value);

Array.Reverse(bytes);
BitArray bitArray = new BitArray(bytes);
```

Which gave me all the bits but completely reversed, reading from [31] to [0].
ultimately, i'm expecting/hoping to get 19349 (4B 95) as my answer.

This is how i was hoping to implement the function:

```
private uint GetValue(uint value, int bitsToGrab, int bitsToMoveOver)
{
    byte[] bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(value);
    BitArray bitArray = new BitArray(bytes);

    uint outputMask = (uint)(1 << (bitsToGrab - 1));
    //now that i have all the bits, i can offset, and grab the ones i want
    for (int i = bitsToMoveOver; i < bitsToGrab; i++)
    {
        if ((Convert.ToByte(bitArray[i]) & 1) > 0)
        {
            outputVal |= outputMask;
        }

        outputMask >>= 1;
   }

}
```

Comment: You want to get 0x4B95 from 0x2C954B ?

Comment: This is ultimately what i came up with.  If anyone would like to improve upon it, i welcome it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 16 least significant bits of `0x2C954B` are `0x954B`. You can get that as follows:

```
int value = 0x2C954B;

int result = value & 0xFFFF;
// result == 0x954B
```

If you want `0x4B95` then you can get that as follows:

```
int result = ((value & 0xFF) << 8) | ((value >> 8) & 0xFF);
// result == 0x4B95
```

---

Try this:

```
uint value = 0x002C954Bu;

int reversed = Reverse((int)value);
// reversed == 0x4B952C00;

int result = Extract(reversed, 16, 16);
// result == 0x4B95
```

with

```
int Extract(int value, int offset, int length)
{
    return (value >> offset) & ((1 << length) - 1);
}

int Reverse(int value)
{
    return ((value >> 24) & 0xFF) | ((value >> 8) & 0xFF00) |
           ((value & 0xFF00) << 8) | ((value & 0xFF) << 24);
}
```

Comment: this works, but the primary problem is that the function has to be modifiable. By that I mean, I need to know how many bits to offset from the beginning, and how many i need to grab.  I cannot guarantee that they will end up on an 8 bit boundary, either. (the 4B95 Result is the one that i need)

Comment: @Jason : please update an question with this details, it would be great if you can provide method signature which are you expect, or describe more detailed which kind of flexibility are you need

Comment: @Jason : approach used by dtb much faster rather than using BitArray and what is more important - you've a chance to understand bitwise operations better

Comment: @dtb - This is much closer, but the offset needs to be 0.  The reason is that although my presented as uints, they are really bytes so when i do the bitconverter.GetBytes, the are placed in the order that i would expect to get them (i.e., the leftmost 16 bits are the ones i want)

Comment: @sllev - I understand bitwise stuff quite well.  I can read and understand what dtb is doing, i just couldn't come up with it on my own.  Previously when i had done this kind of thing, we had swapped bytes, so i think that is a main ingredient of what i am missing here.

Comment: @dtb - im going to accept your answer bc i believe you answered the question as i described it. I realized that i mistated a few things and to back track and retry to explain, i would only cause more confusion...

Answer (score 1):

unit - 32bits
Basically you should set 16 most significant bits to zero, so use bitwise `AND` operator:

```
uint newValue = 0x0000FFFF & uintValue;
```

Comment: I updated my problem statement.  The data is given to me as a uint, but it is really 4 bytes.  
Basically, i have a long stream of data that is passed to me as uints, and i need to grab chunks of data out of that stream (8 bits here, 24 there, etc).  The result that i listed above is the correct result based on my input data, i'm just trying to get the bits right.

Comment: Bitwise OR `|` does not set the 16 most significant bits to zero. `0x0000FFFF | 0x2C954B` results in `0x2CFFFF`. Do you mean bitwise AND `&`?